# Why do write() and read() appear to write and read more than a byte?

Tags: java, file-io, stream, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

In `Java`, the maximum value that a `byte` can hold is 127, which is 8 bits. Also, the read()  method that `FileInputStream` uses (which it inherits from `InputStream`) states that it only reads one `byte`, and the write() method that `FileOutputStream` uses (which it inherits from `OutputStream`) states that it only writes one `byte`. However, when I pass a number greater than 127 but less than 256 to write() and then read() it, I get a character with a decimal value that is indeed between 127 and 255. This seems to show that write() can actually write 9 bits instead of 8, and that read() can actually read 9 bits instead of 8. So, my question is how is this possible? How can read() read more than a `byte` and how can write() write more than a `byte`? Is there something else I'm missing?

As a further example, say I pass the integer 1000 to write(). write() then outputs a character, which read() then reads as having a decimal value of 232. This seems to occur because 1000 - 512 - 256 = 232, which again seems to show that write() and read() write and read 9 bits (up to 255) rather than a byte (8 bits, of up to 127). As it seems to me, write() is writing the lower 9 bits of 1000, which read() then reads, which in this case gives 232.

I have posted the program I'm using to test this all out. Also, I am fairly new to `Java`, so any help or thoughts are much appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestingCharsAndBytes 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        FileOutputStream output = null;
        FileInputStream input = null;       
        try
        {
            output = new FileOutputStream(".../testFileIO1.txt");
            input = new FileInputStream(".../testFileIO1.txt");

            // Stuff to try:


            doFileResult(512,output,input);
            doFileResult(128,output,input);
            doFileResult(256,output,input);
            doFileResult(257,output,input);
            doFileResult(160,output,input);
            doFileResult(289,output,input);
            doFileResult(1000,output,input);
            doFileResult(2000,output,input);            
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occurred.");
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error closing file.");
            }           
        }
    }   
    public static void doFileResult(int toWrite, FileOutputStream outStream, FileInputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("******************");
        outStream.write(toWrite);

        int x = inputStream.read();
        char y = (char) x;

        System.out.println("Integer passed to write: " + toWrite);
        System.out.println("Input integer read: " + x);
        System.out.println("Input character read (after casting to char): " + y);
        System.out.println();       
    }
}
```

Comment: [Per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read--), `read()` uses -1 as a special value to indicate EOF. If the actual range of byte (-128..127) were used, -1 would be a valid byte.

Comment: (I would also like to comment that yes, 8 bits is 256, but in Java, 8 bits for a byte only gives 127, so in order to get a value up to 256 (255), I would think that would mean 9 bits are needed in Java)

Comment: @Andy Turner - yes, I've looked at the docs; my question though is that they state the range should be from -128 to 127, meaning read() should return an integer that has a max value of 127; but that's not the case. I can return an integer from read() that goes up to 255, even though the docs for read state that it can only read one byte (8 bits, so a max value of 127 in Java)

Comment: I’m not sure what docs you’re reading.  The [documentation for InputStream.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) is very clear: “The value byte is returned as an `int` in the range `0` to `255`.”

Comment: @VGR - ok, yes; the link you gave was a second link found in Andy Turner's comment. Thank you. I guess my question is then just due to 0 to 255 vs -128 to 127 that happens due to the byte data type being signed.

Comment: Pretty much.  A signed byte and an unsigned byte are actually a matter of treating the exact same bits as either representing a signed value or representing an unsigned value.  Both -1 and 255 represent the eight bits 11111111.

Answer (score 3):

[Per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read--), `read()` uses -1 as a special value to indicate EOF. If the actual range of byte (-128..127) were used, -1 would be a valid byte.

As stated in the documentation of the base method, [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--):

> The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.

The idiomatic way to write code reading from a stream is something like:

```
while (true) {
  int v = stream.read();
  if (v == -1) {
    break;
  }
  byte b = (byte) v;
  // Do something.
}
```

The cast to byte will "correctly" map the int 0..255  into the byte -128..127, because a narrowing cast from 32 to 8 bits will simply keep the 8 least significant bits.

Comment: So then read() is reading a byte, but viewed as an integer, it's range is from 0 to 255, but casting that into a byte will make it be from -128 to 127?

Comment: @mishar A byte is 8 bits. The value can be interpreted as either *unsigned* (0 to 255) or *signed*. The standard for signed is [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), giving a range of -128 to 127, with the positive values having the same bit-pattern as the unsigned value. Since `read()` needed an extra value to indicate EOF, they decided to return the byte as unsigned and use -1 for EOF, even though the Java `byte` is a signed value. Whether unsigned or signed, it's still an 8-bit binary value.